# error message: the directory name is invalid while clone repository for a new project the first time

Tags: git, github, rstudio

While I am trying to clone the repository for my new project for the first time using RStudio, I got an error message said: "The directory name is invalid".

My directory name is C:\Users\wenya\projects

I search on the internet but cannot find how to fix it.

Here is the git status.

**In terminal**

wenya@DESKTOP-IG780KO  ~/projects (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    .Rhistory
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

**In Console**

> getwd()

[1] "C:/Users/wenya/projects"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, is there any other repositories in \projects? Maybe you have to add new dir for cloned project? It's not a problem with slash/backslash path name? Could try this few tips :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I fixed the problem by specifying "Create project as subdirectory of".